# NTLM authentication for OpenRasta

Tags: restful-authentication, ntlm, openrasta

Following from my previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9292350/pki-authentication-for-openrasta) regarding OpenRasta authentication, I'd like to know if NTLM authentication can be configured for OpenRasta service that is running as executable outside IIS.

Cheers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry, I didn't read the question carefully enough. Unfortunately, I don't believe you can do this out-of-the-box. There is an `HttpListenerHost` provided by OpenRasta which encapsulates a [System.Net.HttpListener](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/34xswsd2.aspx) instance as a **private** variable. See the code in [this forum thread](https://groups.google.com/group/openrasta/browse_thread/thread/ad9bcb7665998520?fwc=1) to see how to use the `HttpListenerHost` in a Console app. If the `HttpListener` variable were `public` or at least `protected` it should be a simple matter of setting the `AuthenticationSchemes` property along the lines of this code:

```
var host = new HttpListenerHost();
host.Listener.AuthenticationSchemes = AuthenticationSchemes.Ntlm;
```

If you really need this capability, you can get the source for OpenRasta and update it to expose the underlying `HttpListener` variable so you can configure it to your heart's content.

===================>>
ORIGINAL ANSWER FOR IIS:

First you create a standard WebForms or MVC project configured for OpenRasta as shown in the [Getting Start wiki page.](https://github.com/openrasta/openrasta/wiki/Building-Your-First-OpenRasta-Website) Next, configure the project as described in this [Wrox article](http://www.wrox.com/WileyCDA/Section/ASP-NET-3-5-Windows-Based-Authentication.id-310905.html) to support Windows authentication. Supporting Windows authentication will enable both [NTLM & Kerberos](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754628%28v=WS.10%29.aspx) authentication.

Comment: On the IIS bit, how do you then retrieve the security context in your app, would it be available on ICommunicationContext? Thanks

Comment: I think I can point you in the right direction on accessing the ICommunicationContext but I don't have right now to check it out. This [blog post](http://codebetter.com/sebastienlambla/2011/09/14/extending-configuration-in-openrasta-2-1/) shows extension points in OpenRasta 2.1 where the ICommunicationContext can be accessed in the pipeline.

Comment: Thanks Sixto, I know how to get ICommunicationContext, my question is rather if user credentials are available on it and if not how can I get them?

Comment: The HttpListenerCommunicationContext has a User property which has the credentials but I don't know which implementation of ICommunicationObject exists under ASP.NET when OpenRasta spins up. You could check in debug mode to dig into the ICommunicationContext instance for a similar property.

Comment: In both HttpListener and asp.net, the ICommunicationContext.User property is set to whatever flows from the hosting environment, and the same happens with the authentication modules.